# How to pass an image in Secondary Tile in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

I'm looking for a way to pass an image as the string and covert it to image type BitmapImage on the next page since I know that we could not pass an image itself to the next page or trying to serialize imageSource by any phone state, it will give an error. What I have been trying is passing it as part of uri parameter and get it by using `NavigationContext.QueryString` but the data I got out of it is always **"{System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage}"**; therefore, no image display on the page. Understanding that I could use "`PhoneApplicationService.Current.State as BitmapImage`" to show the image, but in my application, I want to use Secondary Tile which is linked directly to the pinned page and passby all its previous pages; therefore, the when the application is launched from secondary tile, the PhoneApplication.Current.State is not populated as expected. So, I don't reply completely on any phone state for Secondary Tile.

Is there any alternative to overcome this, could you advise by showing an example?

My current code: Product Detail.xaml.cs

```
        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

            /***
             * 
             *  Trying to get image from uri parameter and covert it to BitmapImage using getImage(string) method in App.xaml.cs
             *  
             *   public ImageSource getImage(string p)
                {
                    return new BitmapImage(new Uri(p, UriKind.Relative));

                }
             * 
             * */

            item_image.Source = ((App)Application.Current).getImage(NavigationContext.QueryString["pro_image"]);


            if (!(IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains("item_name")))
            {
                IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Add("item_name", PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["pro_name"]);

            }

            ShellTile secondaryTile = this.FindTile(SecondaryTileUriSource);

            if (secondaryTile != null)
            {

                // *****************************************************      tile.Delete();


                txtb_product_name.Text = PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["pro_name"] as string;

                txtb_product_name.Text = PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["pro_name"] as string;



            }
        }
```

Here is the produt list.xaml.cs where a list of products is listed for user to select one, and all related information about this selected product it will be show at Product Detail.xaml page.

Product list.xaml.cs

```
  private void lst_product_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (lst_product.SelectedItem != null)
            {
                PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["pro_name"] = (lst_product.SelectedItem as ProductsDry).ItemDryName;
                PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["pro_id"] = (lst_product.SelectedItem as ProductsDry).ItemDryId;
              PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["pro_image"] = (lst_product.SelectedItem as ProductsDry).ItemDryImage;
                PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["ItemDryIngridient"] = (lst_product.SelectedItem as ProductsDry).ItemDryIngredients;
                PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["ItemDryUse"] = (lst_product.SelectedItem as ProductsDry).ItemDryUse;
                PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["ItemDryDesc1"] = (lst_product.SelectedItem as ProductsDry).ItemDryDesc1;
                PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["ItemDryDesc2"] = (lst_product.SelectedItem as ProductsDry).ItemDryDesc2;
                PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["ItemDryUse"] = (lst_product.SelectedItem as ProductsDry).ItemDryUse;

                IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Clear(); 
                NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/All Files/Product Files/Dry/Product Detail.xaml?&pro_name=" + (lst_product.SelectedItem as ProductsDry).ItemDryName + "&pro_image=" + (lst_product.SelectedItem as ProductsDry).ItemDryImage, UriKind.Relative));
            }
            else return;
        }

        protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
            IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Clear();
        }
```

On the product detail page, user can pin the page for his favorite product, at here I have problem with image that send from product list to product detail.

Let me know if you need further information, thanks.

Comment: Show the code example of what you're doig right now. You could try and serialize the image itself as base64, and pass it through query parameters, you can also pass the location of the image, if it exists on somewhere.

Comment: @Erti-ChrisEelmaa-I editted my question to add my code, thanks

Comment: @Erti-ChrisEelmaa any comment?

Comment: It's a bit hard to see what is going on. I see the OnNavigatedTo method that tries to access QueryString("pro_image"). Where is the code that fills this pro_image? Nobody fills this anywhere. Try and see if you can add relevant code and strip anything else that's not necessary.

Comment: @Erti-ChrisEelmaa I edited my question for some more detail. Hope can make you a bit clearer my problem, please let me know if it is not, thanks

Comment: ItemDryImage is BitmapIMage as you see. You should maybe pass the ItemDryImage.UriSource to pass the Uri of Image?

Comment: @Erti-ChrisEelmaa I followed as you said and I set `IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Add("isolated_image", NavigationContext.QueryString["pro_image"] as string);` to store image uri source to isolated storage for next start from secondary tile and ` item_image.Source = ((App)Application.Current).getImage(IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["isolated_image"] as string);` to display an image on image control. However, when I tried pinning the page, it showed the same error **System.Windows.Media.ImageSource' cannot be serialized** I'm sure that I don't try to serial image

Comment: Instead, what I did is to try to get the image uri source as you said and convert it to bitmapImage using getImage(), it's not wrong, is it? because I did not serialize the image object but is uri source. I don't know why still this error..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18502233/how-to-navigate-with-objects-in-windows-phone-8 You can check this one. The other way is to pass the "image ACTUAL harddisk location", you can get this through UriSource.ToString() or UriSource.OriginalString.

Comment: @Erti-ChrisEelmaa before I have also tried the similar way that mentioned in the link: item_image.Source=PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["pro_image"] as bitmapImage, that way it can show the image as usual but when I pressed pin button, it was the same error "System.Windows.Media.ImageSource' cannot be serialized". Could you show me how to pass the image actual harddisk location the other way that you mentioned? thanks

Comment: You pass the same way, through query string, but instead of UriSource, you pass the UriSourceInstance.ToString() or UriSourcInstance.OriginalString.